# Delayed_Job on Heroku showing "Forbidden" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job gem on a heroku deployment. It has been working fine for a few months, but suddenly when I try to access to access mydomain.com/delayed_job it shows one word: "Forbidden"

When I check heroku logs it doesn't show an error, but does show that the page was requested.

Any idea why this would happen? It is especially confusing since it has been working fine until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I tried accessing the same page in a different browser and it works. Therefore the error likely has something to do with the local browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

I had this too; it seems to be similar to [the problem described in this issue](https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web/issues/68). The CSRF protection gets false positives.

In my case, I only use DelayedWebAdmin in development, so I created an initializer to disable session protection. This would probably be a bad idea in production, but here's how to disable it in development:

`config/initializers/delayed_job_web.rb`:

```ruby
if Rails.env.development?
    class DelayedJobWeb
        disable :sessions
        set :protection, false
    end
end
```

Comment: This will resolved the issue, However you can create the file with any name and place it inside the initializers folder.